# Relationship between 10 yield and P/E in Equity valuation

Tags: equities

I've been asked this question in an interview, what's the link between a certain level of yield 10y and P/E  ? for example a company with 28x P/E what that means in a yield ?

Can someone help me understand this ?

Comment: Earnings yield is the Earnings per Share (EPS) over the share price. E.g. if the stock price is USD 100 and EPS is USD 5.00, the stock would have an earnings yield of 5%. P/E is the inverse - P/EPS or 20 in my example. If you have 28, you can use  1/28 to get to roughly 3.6% yield.

Comment: It's called the [FED model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fed_model).  Buffett likes to use it (plenty of evidence online), Goldman thinks it's flawed according to [CNBC](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/06/28/goldman-sachs-calls-warren-buffetts-favorite-method-to-value-the-stock-market-flawed.html).

Comment: You may find this useful: https://www.aqr.com/Insights/Research/Journal-Article/Fight-the-Fed-Model